# creating multiple objects graphics

Tags: python, python-3.x, graphics

Heres my code. Im using graphics.py by zelle. My objective is to create multiple objects (more than one) but it can get ugly if i were to draw more than ten. I was just wondering how do you simplify the code in helper_function() without creating the object one by one? including different colours.

```
def main_function():
      win = GraphWin ("Example" , 1000,1000)
      win.setBackground("green")

def helper_function():
      b = Circle(Point(50,50),20)
      b.setFill("blue")
      b.draw(win)

      b = Circle(Point(50,100),20)
      b.setFill("blue")
      b.draw(win)

      b = Circle(Point(50,150),20)
      b.setFill("blue")
      b.draw(win)

      g = Circle(Point(300,50),20)
      g.setFill("green")
      g.draw(win)

      g = Circle(Point(350,50),20)
      g.setFill("green")
      g.draw(win)

      g = Circle(Point(400,50),20)
      g.setFill("green")
      g.draw(win) 

      g = Circle(Point(450,200),20)
      g.setFill("green")
      g.draw(win)
```

Comment: You can create a list of dicts which include x, y, and color values and loop through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a list of tuples which contain x,y,radius and color and loop over it and apply common methods to object created as follows:

```
from graphics import *

def main_function():
    win = GraphWin ("Example" , 1000,1000)
    win.setBackground("green")
    circle_params = [(50, 50, 20, "blue"),
                   (50 ,100, 20, "blue"),
                   (50,100, 20, "green"),
                   (300,50, 20, "green"),
                   (350,50, 20, "green"),
                   (400,50, 20, "green"),
                   (450,50, 20, "green"),
                   ]
    helper_function(win, circle_params)

def helper_function(win, circle_params):
    for param in circle_params:
        a = Circle(Point(param[0], param[1]), param[2]).setFill(param[3]).draw(win)
```

OR :

```
 def helper_function(win, circle_params):
    circle_obj_lst = [Circle(Point(param[0], param[1]), param[2]).setFill(param[3]).draw(win) for param in circle_params]
```

OR

```
def helper_function(win, circle_params):
    circle_obj_lst = map(lambda param:Circle(Point(param[0], param[1]), param[2]).setFill(param[3]).draw(win) ,circle_params)
```

hope this helps :)